# Vsphere 6 HP DL385 G7 AMD-V won't enable

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, hp-proliant

I'm not able to get hyperthreading inside vsphere 6 working on my HP DL385 G7.

- AMD-V is enabled in BIOS
- BIOS is updated to latest version
- Vsphere 6 U3 HP branded is running on this host
- Following this command `esxcfg-info|grep "\----\HV Support"` from (https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1011712) gives me number 3, which should mean that AMD-V is enabled and can be used.
- CPU is a AMD Opteron 6238

Does anyone have a way to AMD-V working?

[image]

Comment: whats the actual problem you are experiencing, and how does it manifest? How many cores do you have, how many should you have.

Comment: This cpu is a 12 core cpu with AMD-V enabled it should give me 24 logical cores to use. At this moment hyperthreading had the status N/A on the esxi host.

Comment: How many cores does vsphere say you have available?

Comment: vSphere says I have 12 cores available. See start post for screenshot.

Comment: So I just read up on it, since I haven't used AMD in a long time, and there is no hypterthreading equivalent for AMD. AMD-V are virtualization functions, but they do not increase number of available cores.

Comment: Aah thank you, I thought that Intels Hyperthreading was called AMD-V on the AMD site.